# Python - List - unable to detect size

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a function which is aimed to parse a text file, found a regex match (ip + port) and return a list with unique value:

```
def parser (file):
    ip_list = []
    pattern = re.compile('[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}.port.*')
    for i, line in enumerate(open(file)):
        for match in re.finditer(pattern, line):
            ip_list.append(match.group())
    unique_ip = reduce(lambda l, x: l if x in l else l+[x], ip_list,[])
    return [unique_ip]
```

This works pretty fine, but for some reason I'm unable to iterate on returned list object and get current size.
Example, if I print out

```
print(parser(file))
```

and I obtain this output:

```
[['212.162.82.10 port 80', '212.162.81.10 port 8081']]
```

I get a list size of 1 (despite there's 2 elements):

```
print(len(parser(file)))
1
```

I'm not getting where I'm making mistake.
thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an 2 dimensional array with the double brackets `[[`

Try `len(parser(file[0]))` instead or update the code by changing `return [unique_ip]`
 to `return unique_ip`

Answer (score 1):

If you notice the output has two brackets, which means a list inside of a list. You're iterating the outermost list, which only has one element: the inner list. So the length really is one.

Instead of returning `[unique_ip]`, just do `return unique_ip`.